# Task Scheduler half completes task from batch file, then gives (0x1)

Tags: windows-10, batch, scheduled-tasks, 7-zip

I am attempting to use Task Scheduler to automatically create a backup of a couple of folders in  a location at the end of the day. I am using 7zip as my archive program. The batch file that I am using is very simple:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "C:\Users\testcomp\Desktop\Combined Backups\Combined Directory %DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~10,4%.zip" "P:\Engineering\Test Bench\Combined Directory\"
```

When I run the text in a command window the appropriate zipped folder is created. When I double click on the batch file the appropriate zipped folder is created. This leads me to believe that the file is formatted properly.

When I attempt to run the batch file through Task Scheduler, a zip folder is created in the appropriate location with the correct filename. However, the file is empty, having not actually zipped anything together. In Task Scheduler, the (0x1) error is noted. I am not sure why the Task Scheduler appears to do some of the task but not all of it.

Some additional/restated info:

| Category | Info |
| --- | --- |
| OS | Windows 10 |
| Archive Program | 7Zip |
| "Run with highest privileges" | Checked |
| "Triggers" | On a schedule, One time (I will change this once I know the dang thing works) |
| "Action" | Start a program |
| "Program/Script" | C:\Users\testcomp\Desktop\Combined Backups\Combined Directory\CombinedBackupFile.bat |
| "Start in" | C:\Users\testcomp\Desktop\Combined Backups\Combined Directory\ |
| "Conditions" | (None) |

Any assistance on the matter would be greatly appreciated. (sorry about the awkward formatting)

Comment: Common reasons for the 0x1 error is insufficient privileges or permission. Make sure you are using a folder to extract to that is not secured. Try extracting to c:\temp .

Comment: As you are *Running with highest privilege* there will be no drive mappings. Drive P: doesn't exist. Use UNC paths if your program supports it `\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext`.

Comment: I checked that all folders involved had no abnormal levels of security. These are folders that I have read/write access to. In addition. I attempted to use the UNC path for that P: drive and I got the same result.

Comment: While it doesn't resolve the issue, you could bypass the `.bat` file altogether and add the commands directly to the task.

Comment: You may want to redirect the 7z command stdout and stderr to a log file, to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Apologies, I am not super familiar with these commands. I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-windows-cmd-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file) that I can use `dir > a.txt 2>&1` (or maybe its `dir 1> a.txt 2>&1`)to get those commands to fire, however I can't tell if its actually doing anything. A file by the name "a.txt" gets created in the folder but it doesn't have any info besides stuff about the folder itself.